# How do I get Karma and PhantomJS to run multiple Jasmine specrunner html files?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, phantomjs, karma-runner

I am brand new to javascript unit testing.  I am trying to get javascript code coverage as part of our automated build.  The project has several jsp pages each with its own javascript file.  I have written a dozen Jasmine spec runner html files that work.

I have Karma 0.10, Karma-coverage, and PhantomJS 1.9.2 installed.

When I start karma I get a PhantomJS SyntaxError "Parse error".  It seems that PhantomJS does not like my Jasmine spec runner html files.  The different spec runner files include different javascript files and they can not all be loaded at once.

I seem to be missing some part to tie all of these things together, but I don't know what.

```
// Karma configuration
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
    basePath: '',

    plugins:[
             'karma-jasmine',
             'karma-coverage',
             'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
             'karma-html2js-preprocessor'
             ],

    // frameworks to use
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'src/test/javascript/*.html'
    ],

    preprocessors: {
      '**/main/webapp/**/*.js': 'coverage'
    },

    reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],

    coverageReporter: {
      type: 'html',
      dir: 'target/karma/coverageHTML/'
    },

    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: false,
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    captureTimeout: 60000,
    singleRun: true
  });
};
```